# SSIS export multiple tables to flat files

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have to export some tables from a database to flat files.

Destination is fixed and the output file name will be 'table_name.txt', where table_name is the name of the respective tables.

Is there any way to do this without script task and BCP utility?

Comment: How about the Import Export wizard of SQL Server?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx